# XmlElement to string conversion

Tags: c#, .net, xml, type-conversion

Is there some simple way to convert `XmlElement` to `string` ?

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Jon Skeet Just some string with all the nodes , I need it for logging

Comment: All the nodes in what format? Please give an example. For example, does the `OuterXml` property give you what you need?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This will get the content of the element if the content is text:

```
element.Value
```

This will get the content of the element as XML:

```
element.InnerXml
```

This will get the element and its content as XML

```
element.OuterXml
```

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx) or [`InnerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx) properties of the element.

However, without further details of exactly what you are looking, I can't help more.

Update:

Seeing as you want the XML of all nodes, using [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml.aspx) or [`OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) should do nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have this `XmlElement`:

```
<node>
  Hello
  <effect color="pink">
    World
  </effect>
</node>
```

With `Console.Write(xmlElement.Inner)` you see the inside of your node:

```
Hello <effect color="pink">World</effect>
```

With `Console.Write(xmlElement.Outer)` you get everything:

```
<node>Hello <effect color="pink">World</effect></node>
```

With `Console.Write(xmlElement.Value)` you get nothing, because [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value(v=VS.110).aspx) always returns null for an XML element.

Comment: Explaining it with the Example gives more insight. Thanks. Voted Up!